# How do you enforce Content-Type in S3 pre-signed POSTs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to rework uploads for my application to go from:

1. Client uploads file to API
2. API uploads file to S3

to

1. Client requests pre-signed URL from API
2. API generates and responds with URL
3. Client uploads to S3

The one thing I am struggling with is limiting what files can be uploaded. We want to allow for uploading images and videos, but not potentially dangerous files like executables. I've been trying to utilize the Bucket Policy to enforce  a `$Content-Type` of `video/mp4`, but I am still able to upload images. Here is how I am generating the URL (PHP in this case, mostly taken from the [S3 docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-presigned-post.html)):

```
$formInputs = ['acl' => 'public-read', 'key' => 'test1.mp4', 'Content-Type' => 'video/mp4'];
$options = [
    ['acl' => 'public-read'],
    ['bucket' => $bucket],
    ['key' => 'test1.mp4'],
    ['eq', '$Content-Type', 'video/mp4']
];
$expires = '+2 hours';
$postObject = new \Aws\S3\PostObjectV4(
    $client,
    $bucket,
    $formInputs,
    $options,
    $expires
);
```

After plugging the `$postObject->getFormInputs()` into Postman and POSTing an image as the file, it accepts the upload. If I request the file from S3, I am able to access it however it is returned with `Content-Type: video/mp4` and doesn't play in a browser; but I am still able to upload the file which doesn't seem to make sense.

It seems that this option only mandates that the field be included in the form inputs (if I remove the `Content-Type` field from the inputs, it fails). The `Content-Type` header seems to be completely irrelevant, as does the actual mime-type of the file. If that is the case, this rule seems incredibly useless for POST/PUT (maybe less so for GET).

Is it possible to restrict the file type that is allowed to be uploaded without relying on the data that is sent in the form inputs? Or do I need to check the file after upload either in my application or in Lambda and verify that it is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The policy only controls what is allowed/required in the form.  Changing/removing fields results in an error because the upload no longer matches the policy.  There is no validation of whether the uploaded data is in fact of the specified `Content-Type`.

If you need to validate it, you have to validate it after the fact -- in your application or in Lambda, as you suggested.

Comment: This is what I believed was the case. I guess I will have to handle it separately, which is annoying but not the end of the world by any means. Assuming no one says otherwise, I'll mark this as the answer in a few days.

Comment: Sounds good.  S3 is concerned only with storing bytes of data, not interpreting payload -- and enforcing `Content-Type` would require that it S3 interpret the payload.

Comment: Yeah and that makes sense from their standpoint. Just slightly annoying from ours.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Hey, late but, can you provide example of processor lambda validation? if i upload file whatever Content-Type i want, it is saved with that Content-Type in s3, and when fetching the object in processor, it will return that same type it was uploaded with, not the actual one. so what do we actually process?